# How to write mockito for below method

Tags: mockito, powermock

```
public List<Locatins> fetchLocations() {
        BasicAuthRestTemplate restTemplate = new BasicAuthRestTemplate(config.getUsername(),config.getPassword());
        String locationsOData =  restTemplate.getForObject(config.getOdataUrl()+config.getLocations(), String.class);
        String results = StringUtility.changeUIFieldCase(locations);
        return map.Locations(results);
    }




@Test
    public void fetchLocationsTest() throws Exception {�

        List<Locations> li = new ArrayList<>();
        String locationData = "noting";
        when(config.getUsername()).thenReturn(“test1”);
        when(config.getPassword()).thenReturn("test12”);
        when(config.getTdsOdataUrl()).thenReturn("https://localhost:8080");
        when(config.getLocations()).thenReturn("/locations");
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(BasicAuthRestTemplate.class);
        PowerMockito.whenNew(BasicAuthRestTemplate.class).withArguments(config.getUsername(), config.getPassword()).thenReturn(restTemplate);
        PowerMockito.when(restTemplate.getForObject("https://localhost:8080/locations",String.class)).thenReturn(locationData);
    �
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical problem with code like this is that you coupled it strongly with its dependency (`BasicAuthRestTemplate`):

```
BasicAuthRestTemplate restTemplate = new BasicAuthRestTemplate(config.getUsername(),config.getPassword());
```

This code will always use this restTemplate and never anything else. You are binding together two pieces of software very strictly. This means that you a) cannot simply use your code in other situations (for example, if you get another REST service that doesn't use Basic Authentication, you have to change this code) and b) that it may be hard to test, because literally the only thing this code can do is connect to something via Basic Authentication.

Powermock and similar tools are pretty much always pointing out a code smell. If you need very complicated and complex tools to test your code, chances are that the code is bad.

So, if at all possible, I suggest refactoring your code by injecting the RestTemplate:

```
public List<Locatins> fetchLocations(RestTemplate restTemplate) {        
        String locationsOData =  restTemplate.getForObject(config.getOdataUrl()+config.getLocations(), String.class);
        String results = StringUtility.changeUIFieldCase(locations);
        return map.Locations(results);
    }
```

This would be the most easy way, but of course you can inject it into the class via Spring (`@Autowired`, etc.), too. The important point is that you separate the dependency from the code by injecting it into it instead of "hard-wiring" it.

With the code above, you can test it much simpler...

```
RestTemplate template = mock(BasicAuthRestTemplate.class);
Mockito.when(template...).thenReturn(...);
List<Locations> result = fetchLocations(template);
assertThat(result)....
```

Of course, if you cannot refactor the code, then you are probably screwed a bit and will need complex tools (it's probably possible somehow with bytecode manipulation, but it's nothing I would want to do, to be honest).